# How to find again Youtube videos that appeared once on your feed and you lost?

Tags: youtube

I just opened the Youtube Android app and immediately closed it. The instant I closed it I saw a bit of the thumbnail of the next video on the feed. I wanted to watch it. But it was too late, I had already closed the app. And when I reopened it, the feed had new videos and when I scrolled I couldn't find the video I had seen before

**How can I find this video again? Or my only option is to wait for it to appear on my feed again and wish I'm lucky?**

Solutions that could have worked in other situations but not now:

1. Opening the multitasking pane and seeing the title of the video there. Or if the title was hidden and only showed the thumbnail, screenshotting just the thumbnail for then doing a reverse image search. This didn't work now because I had just seen a bit of the thumbnail, not enough for doing a reverse image search.

[image: Android multitasking pane]

2. Exiting the app by using the "home" button, so that when you open the Youtube app again, the feed is in the exact same position as when you left. But I used the "back" action button, so the app closed for real and when I opened it again, the feed refreshed and it had different videos

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. AFAIK, there's no history of Feed, and since it's generated on-the-fly, I think you can only hope for it to come again by exiting and reopening the app many times....

Comment: there is no way, except that if you continue to interact with videos similar to the one you saw, the chances are the algorithm may be nice and serve it to you again.